# Suggestions on how to remove duplicate code in python

Tags: python

I'm using Pyqt5, each functions is passed a different Pandas data frame, depending on the data a different graph will get created. There seems to be a lot of duplicate code, i was wondering if you could provide suggestions on how to refactor the code below.

## Connecting signals and slots

```
self.ui.PlotA.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartA(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.A))      
self.ui.PlotB.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartB(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.B))      
self.ui.PlotC.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartC(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.C))      
self.ui.PlotD.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartD(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.D))      
self.ui.PlotE.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartE(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.E))      
self.ui.PlotF.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartF(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.F))      
self.ui.PlotG.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartG(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.G))      
self.ui.PlotH.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartH(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.H))      
self.ui.PlotI.clicked.connect(lambda:self.CreateChartI(self.ui.Title,self.ui.StartDate,self.ui.EndDate,self.I))
```

## Functions to connect to the push button

```
    def CreateChartA(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):        
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data) 
        c.PlotChartA()

    def CreateChartB(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChartB()

    def CreateChartC(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChartC()

    def CreateChartD(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChartD()

    def CreateChartE(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChartE()

    def CreateChartF(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChartF()

    def CreateChartG(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChartG()

    def CreateChartH(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChartH()

    def CreateChartI(self,Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data):
        c = Charts(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChartI()
```

## Chart Class

```
class Charts():

    def __init__(self, Title,StartDate, EndDate, Data):
        self.Title = Title
        self.StartDate = StartDate
        self.EndDate = EndDate
        self.Data = Data

    # plot surface data
    def PlotChartA(self):           
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart A')
        plt.show()  

        #print(self.Data.head())


    def PlotChartB(self):

        plt.figure(2)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart B')
        plt.show()   

    def PlotChartC(self):

        plt.figure(2)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart C')
        plt.show()  

        #print(self.Data.head())



    def PlotChartD(self):

        plt.figure(4)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart D')
        plt.show()   

    def PlotChartE(self):
        plt.figure(5)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart E')
        plt.show()   

    def PlotChartF(self):
        plt.figure(6)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart F')
        plt.show()   

    def PlotChartG(self):
        plt.figure(7)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart G')
        plt.show()   

    def PlotChartH(self):
        plt.figure(8)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart H')
        plt.show()

    def PlotChartI(self):
        plt.figure(9)
        plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        plt.ylabel('Chart I')
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by modifying the chart class to be ambiguous,

```
class Chart:
    ...

    def plot_chart(self, figure, plot, ylabel):           
        plt.figure(figure)
        plt.plot(plot)
        plt.ylabel(ylabel)
        plt.show()
```

Then you can make a function to create the charts:

```
def create_chart(self, num, name, Title, StartDate, EndDate, Data):
        c = Chart(Title,StartDate,EndDate,Data)
        c.PlotChart(num, [1, 2, 3, 4], f'Chart {name}')
```

Then to connect them use `getattr` and a loop:

```
  for num, name in enumerate('ABCDEFGH', 1):
        plot = getattr(self.ui, f'Plot{name}')
        plot.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.create_chart(num, name,
                self.ui.Title,
                self.ui.StartDate,
                self.ui.EndDate,
                self.A))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by removing all the explicit references to specific charts in the method names of `Charts`:

```py
class Charts():

    def __init__(self, Title, StartDate, EndDate, Data):
        self.Title = Title
        self.StartDate = StartDate
        self.EndDate = EndDate
        self.Data = Data

    def PlotChart(self, Chart):
        if Chart == 'A':
            # plot surface data
            plt.figure(1)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
            #print(self.Data.head())
        elif Chart == 'B':
            plt.figure(2)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        elif Chart == 'C':
            plt.figure(2)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])

            #print(self.Data.head())
        elif Chart == 'D':
            plt.figure(4)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        elif Chart == 'E':
            plt.figure(5)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        elif Chart == 'F':
            plt.figure(6)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        elif Chart == 'G':
            plt.figure(7)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        elif Chart == 'H':
            plt.figure(8)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        elif Chart == 'I':
            plt.figure(9)
            plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
        else:
            return
        plt.ylabel('Chart ' + Chart)
        plt.show()
```

Then your `CreateChart` functions all simplify into one:

```py
    def CreateChart(self, Chart, Title, StartDate, EndDate, Data):
        c = Charts(Title, StartDate, EndDate, Data)
        c.PlotChart(Chart)
```

and the connecting functions likewise:

```py
for Chart in 'ABCDEFGHJI':
    fn = lambda: self.CreateChart(Chart, self.ui.Title, self.ui.StartDate, self.ui.EndDate, getattr(self, Chart))
    getattr(self.ui, 'Plot'+Chart).clicked.connect(fn)
```

A note: the convention in Python is to use lower case and underscores for variable names and function names, such as `title`, `start_date`, `chart`, `plot_chart`, etc., to distinguish them from class names. I would recommend adopting that in your code.